# How to refresh inline form in Admin panel?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-admin

I have model (Category, Item, AttributeCategory,AttributeitemValue), when i add new Item, in item I have AttributeitemValueInline, then i change category in Item, i want get possible Attribute value for Item in which this item includes category.

For example category "Laptop and Tablet" have (RAM and Disk Type), category "bed and chair" have (Width and heigth) , When i add new Item and chose category, inline form Attribute( this inline form in Item, ) make have only attribute value what linked to category. I add Item Laptop imputn name and choose category, inline form catch this value and have only RAM and Disk Type attributess for adding to item. Sorry for my bad English.

How I can dynamically get attribute from category? whtn creating Item?

```
class AttributeItemValueInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = AttributeItemValue


class AttributeItemValueAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    pass

admin.site.register(AttributeItemValue, AttributeItemValueAdmin)

class ItemAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [
        AttributeItemValueInline,
    ]

    def formfield_for_foreignkey(self, db_field, request, **kwargs):
        if db_field.name == "category":
            kwargs["queryset"] = Category.objects.filter(parent__isnull = False)
        return super().formfield_for_foreignkey(db_field, request, **kwargs)

admin.site.register(Item, ItemAdmin)
```

models.py

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 255)
    slug = models.SlugField()
    parent = models.ForeignKey('self',on_delete = models.PROTECT, blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

class Item(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 255)
    slug = models.SlugField()
    description = models.TextField()
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=2,decimal_places=2)
    category = models.ForeignKey('Category', related_name='categories', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

class Attribute(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 255)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name


class Unit(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 255)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

class ImageItem(models.Model):
    picture = models.ImageField()
    item = models.ForeignKey('Item',on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.item.name + " picture"

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.item.name + " picture"

class AttributeCategory(models.Model):
    attribute = models.ForeignKey("Attribute", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    category = models.ForeignKey("Category", on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.category.name + " -> " + self.attribute.name

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.category.name + " -> " + self.attribute.name

class AttributeItemValue(models.Model):
    attribute = models.ForeignKey('Attribute',on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    item = models.ForeignKey('Item',on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    numerical_value = models.DecimalField(max_digits=2,decimal_places=2)
    text_value = models.CharField(max_length = 255)
    unit = models.ForeignKey('Unit',on_delete=models.PROTECT)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.item.name + " -> " + self.attribute.name + " -> Value"


    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.item.name + " -> " + self.attribute.name + " -> Value"
```

[image: class schema]

Comment: It's hard to understand your question. Can you maybe make it more specific by giving an example with example values?

Comment: For example category "Laptop and Tablet" have (RAM and Disk Type),  category "bed and chair" have (Width and heigth) , When i add new Item and chose category, inline form Attribute( this inline form in Item, ) make have only attribute value what linked to category.

I add Item Laptop imputn name and choose category, inline form catch this value and have only RAM and Disk Type attributess for adding to item.

This more clearly or not? Sorry for my bad English.

Comment: Thanks (you should add this to your question rather than just in a comment, as it makes the question more clear). It's not going to be easy to do this in admin. You should consider making your own view and form for this. If the number of categories and attributes is very large, you'll want to use javascript to make an ajax request to fetch the attributes after a category is selected. If not, your javascript would just update the attributes in place.

Comment: Thanks, i hopped on more easy way(

Comment: Actually you can also do it in admin but you’ll still need to override the form and add the javascript to make the choices based on the selection. But there’s no easier way.